# Is there a way to automagically get the ID that the object was allocated in?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Say I do this:

```
@implementation currentViewController
...
SomeClass *myObject = [SomeClass alloc];
```

How can myObject get a reference of currentViewController without sending a message to myObject like this:

```
[myObject wasCreatedIn:self];
```

Side note: Where do action sheets and notifications get displayed in? The current view or the appDelegate window? Does the iphone save a current hierarchy of views or do I have to keep track of it myself?

Comment: Please ask your "side notes" as a separate question-- you won't get answers to fundamentally different questions in one place here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no "automagic" for this. You can create an instance of `SomeClass` anywhere, and alloc/init have no idea where you're calling from unless you want to tell them by creating a property and setting it explicitly as you suggest.

This is true of all objects in general.

`UIViewController`s know who their parents are, though, so if the object you're talking about is a view controller that's been pushed onto a navigation stack or presented modally from another controller, you should be able to figure out who the parent controller is.

Comment: Further info: Remember that objects can even be created in a context where no self exists at all. Objective-C is not purely object-oriented!